# How to call multiple methods from an action listener?

Tags: java, methods

so I'm doing a project for my class and I've come across a bit of an obstacle.

In one whole class (named `GroupProject`) I was able to get my menu to work and show up and everything looked great.
In the same `GroupProject` class I made an action listener class that has Switch statements in it with cases that hold all of the different code for each button that can be pressed.

The problem is it has a ton of methods that it's calling from my `GroupProject` class.

At the moment it works fine, but I want to move the entire action listener class to a new .java file of its own, just so it looks a bit nicer. But I have no idea how to make it so it can actually call the specific methods in the `GroupProject` class.

Here's my action listener class that I want to make its own .java file

```
public class ChoiceHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String yourChoice = event.getActionCommand();

        switch(position)
        {
        case "openingCeremony":
            switch(yourChoice)
            {
                case "c1": charizardChosen(); break;
                case "c2": break;
                case "c3": break;
            }
            break;
        case "charizardChosen":
            switch(yourChoice)
            {
                case "c3": firstBattle(); break;
            }
            break;
        case "firstBattle":
            switch(yourChoice)
            {
                case "c1": attackMenu(); break;
                case "c2": inventoryMenu(); break;
                case "c3": runOption(); break;
            }
            break;
        case "inventoryMenu":
            switch(yourChoice)
            {
                case "c1": firstBattle(); break;
            }
            break;
        case "attackMenu":
            switch(yourChoice)
            {
                case "c1": battleMenu(); break;
                case "c2": firstBattle(); break;
            }
            break;
        case "runOption":
            switch(yourChoice)
            {
                case "c1": firstBattle(); break;
            }
            break;
        case "battleMenu":
            switch(yourChoice)
            {
                case "c3": break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The cases use a `String` (called "position") that changes with each method I call, just so the switch statement can know where I am in the code. I'm not gonna include my GroupProject class, only cause it's around 400 lines, and that might be a bit much.

The "c1" and "c2" and "c3" cases are the different buttons that can be pressed, I just have them named to c1 for choice1 and so on.

I'd love to hear any advice, as my professor probably wouldn't like the fact that I have classes in classes. :\

Comment: You can pass in the GroupProject class and call methods on it. Or you can create an instance of GroupProject here and call methods if you don't have any other information to share. If you use Java 8, then you can return the method body or the name and call the method from the function that calls actionPerformed method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to Java, not quite sure I understand what you're telling me. I did try to pass in GroupProject before, and it didn't underline anything in red, but when I ran the project it gave me an entire console full of errors.

Comment: What do you mean create an instance of GroupProject though?